# error during compiling no such files or directory on textpad

Tags: c++, gcc, textpad

I've downloaded textpad. I changed the modality to make it executable. but whenever I run every cpp program. I get the error gcc:error: no such file or directory during compiling. I have this problem either by running the program on textpad or by running it from the terminal

Comment: Maybe gcc is not in your path. Or your setting for compiling in textpad is wrong. I am not familiar with textpad so I can't help with that.

Comment: As [TextPad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TextPad) is just a text editor (with the option to call external programs), you have to setup the call of `gcc` somewhere in its configuration. It might be pre-configured on installation but that pre-configuration might not match the specific installation path of `gcc` on your system.